# How does Raku deal with the diamond problem (multiple inheritance)?

Tags: multiple-inheritance, raku, diamond-problem

So it's no secret that Raku has multiple inheritance, so that got me wondering: "how does Raku deal with that in any reasonable manner?"

Some preliminary testing reveals that default behaviour is inherited from the *first* class in the inheritance list, that's fine, many other languages do it like that too

```
class A {
    has $.foo = 0;

    method speak {...}
}

class B is A {
    has $.foo = 1;

    method speak {
        say 'moo';
    }
}

class C is A {
    has $.foo = 2;

    method speak {
        say 'baa';
    }
}

class D is B is C {}

class E is C is B {}

say D.new.foo; # prints 1 (from B)
say E.new.foo; # prints 2 (from C)
```

But that got me wondering, what if I want `D` to use `C`'s `speak`?
Due to the inheritance order I get B's by default.

I understand that roles exist to solve this exact issue by facilitating a disambiguation mechanism, but suppose hypothetically I find myself in a situation where I don't have roles at my disposal (boss hates them, inherited a library that doesn't have them, pick your excuse) and really need to disambiguate the inherited classes.

What's the mechanism for dealing with that in Raku?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally you would need to provide a tie-breaker method in the class that has the (potential) ambiguity.  Fortunately, you do not have to create separate methods, as you can call specific versions of methods in a call.

So the answer to your question:  Add a method `speak` to class D, and have that call the `speak` method from class `C`:

```
class D {
    ...
    method speak { self.C::speak }
}
```

And for methods taking parameters, take a `Capture` of all parameters, and pass that on:

```
class D {
    ...
    method foo(|c) { self.C::foo(|c) }
}
```

Note that the "c" in `|c` is just an identifier, it could be any identifier.  But it is sorta customary, at least with Raku core developers, to just use `|c`, with the "c" standing for "capture".

Now, this will cause some overhead, as you would have an extra level of indirection.  Should this turn out to be a performance issue, there's some meta-programming you can do to alias the `speak` method in `D` to the `speak` method in `C`:

```
class D {
    ...
    BEGIN D.^add_method("speak",C.^find_method("speak"));
}
```

This will, at compile time because of the `BEGIN`, add a `Method` object to the `D` class called `speak` that is defined by the `speak` method of class `C`.  Since this is an alias, you don't have to worry about any parameters being passed.